# PCI Simple Communications Controller Driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, parallel-port, expansion-cards, compaq-desktop-computer

I have a Compaq Presario CQ5320F desktop PC (Windows 7 64-bit OS). And it has an PCI extension card with a parallel port. But when I connected a printer that uses a parallel connection it didn't work, and the printer driver installer says that there is no parallel ports available.

In the device manager I see the **PCI Simple Communications Controller** by **Other Devices** marked with a yellow exclamation mark. I checked in properties and at the status it says, "The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28) There is no driver selected for the device information set or element." The Hardware ID is: **PCI\VEN_5372&DEV_6872&SUBSYS_00121000&REV_01**

Can anyone please help me find the correct driver for this?!

Comment: Helping you find the driver for a device ( you provided zero information on the device ) is out of scope for Superuser.

Comment: Who makes the adapter?  Did you contact them/their site to get drivers?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I tried to find it on there site to no avail. One of the sites that Google brought up has this device as **RDH2159 PCI - PARALLEL&DUAL SERIAL Driver for Gigabyte Technology**

Comment: Remove the parallel card, look on the card for most likely the largest chip on the board.  It should have a name and model on it.  A lot of those cards are MOSCHIP brand, but this could be different.

Comment: It isn't that I can't help, I could help, if I had more information about the device.